# Word that means "Sneak and Steal"?

Tags: single-word-requests, archaicisms

I'm looking for a word that combines "Sneak" with "Steal", like:

- *To sneak and steal*

It would be best if it were archaic, but I'd love to hear all possibilities of course. Thank you!

EDIT:

Thanks for the replies so far. I looked up synonyms of steal on google before asking this question, but I missed the obvious second definition.

I will probably just use a synonym of steal, then.

Comment: filch, pilfer, swipe

Comment: defalcate, purloin, misappropriate, peculate; all surreptitiously plundered from google in less than two minutes, thus beating the hidden alarm system and escaping before the police arrived.

Comment: Also 'sneak' is a synonym of 'steal', so you could just use *steal.*

Comment: @Christopher not being perfect synonyms, to sneak something means to steal it in a sneaky way, but to steal it does not necessarily mean sneakily, so they could use *sneak*, but not *steal*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose stealing is usually sneaky. Perhaps you are looking for a word with the right kind of "shape", particularly one with a hint of the archaic?

I think of "pilfer" and "filtch", "purloin", "snaffle"

[Here's a link to some eighteenth century thieves cant;](http://www.pascalbonenfant.com/18c/cant/crime.html#CheatsandTricks) many terms for trickery and thieving.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with ***burglarize***, or the less used ***burgle***.

> : to illegally enter (a building) and steal things
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burglarize)</sub>

If the sneaking and stealing is directly from a person's body, then an apt term would be ***pickpocket***.

> **Pickpocketing** is a form of larceny that involves the stealing of money or other valuables from the person of a victim without their noticing the theft at the time.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickpocketing)</sub>

Comment: Pickpocketing is too specific, and burglary does not imply stealth. Both are good words, though.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: The connotation is stealthy because a burglar usually works in the cover of darkness. But, you are right, I wasn't able to find a term that directly implies stealth except for *pickpocket*.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest "swipe." It can imply stealing something on the sly.

1825, from swipe (v.). The slang sense of "steal, pilfer" appeared 1885, American English; earliest use in prison jargon:

> The blokes in the next cell, little Charley Ames and the Sheeney Kid, they was hot to try it, and swiped enough shoe-lining out of shop No. 5, where they worked, to make us all breeches to the stripes. ["Lippincott's Magazine," vol. 35, June 1885]

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/swipe

Comment: To "swipe" something almost always implies thievery and stealth. Rarely is swiped ever used in a context that does not involve sneaking. I would definitely choose this answer over the others.

Answer (score 1):

How about *to poach*?  The word isn't exactly archaic, but the practice of stealing game, usually by night, from private estates does figure in British history. There are some ballads about the practice. For example:

*I keep my dogs and I keep my ferrets.

I have them in my keeping.

To catch the hares that run by night

When the gamekeeper lies sleeping.*

Comment: Should "catch" in the poem maybe be "poach"? Doesn't make much sense to me otherwise.